# Is $f: \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}, f(x) = 3x + 6$ a bijection? Why?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$f: \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}, f(x) = 3x + 6$

Is $f$ a bijection? If no, explain why it isn’t. If yes, find an expression computing $f^{−1}(y)$ for $y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

How to approach that question?

Comment: Ask yourself whether or not the function is both injective and surjective.  That is to say, will you always get different outputs if you give it different inputs or are there some inputs that give the same output?  Is every element in the codomain actually an output that happens?

Comment: Just try to solve $f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to see that the function's value is a multiple of 3. Is every integer a multiple of 3? No. So which property does that violate?

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(x)=3(x+2),$ the image of $f$ is not all of $\mathbb{Z}$ but only the multiples of $3$. So there can be no inverse map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}.$ But $f$ does happen to be an injection.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use a different approach since it is easy to invert the function.

Suppose for a contradiction that $f$ is a bijection, which implies $f$ is invertible. Then inverse function $f^{-1}$ of $f$ is 
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-6}{3},\ x\in\mathbb{Z}, f^{-1}:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$$
But this is not even a function since $x$ values that are not multiple of $3$ are not even mapped to an element in codomain. So we have a contradiction as required.

Comment: Thank you everyone! So I assume if the function is R→R,g(x) = 3x+6, then it's going to be a bijection, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then, f−1(x)= ((x − 6) / 3), x∈R,f−1 ?

Comment: Then $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-6}{3}, x\in\mathbb{R}, f^{-1}(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks dude for help!

Comment: You're welcome.